# 'TypeError: $(...).characterCounter is not a function' in my jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am practicing the jQuery plugin

i create this plugin :

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $.fn.characterCounter = function () {
        return this.each(function (index, item) {
            $(item).keyup(function updateCharCounter() {
                var $me = $(this),
                    maxLength = parseInt($me.attr('maxlength'), 10),
                    charCount = $me.val().length,
                    $counter = $me.siblings('.limit');

                $counter.text('limit: ' + maxLength + ' characters. remaining: ' + (maxLength - charCount));
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

and my html code :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="short-message" maxlength="100" cols="8"></textarea>
    <p class="limit">limit: 100 characters</p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="short-shory" maxlength="150" cols="8"></textarea>
    <p class="limit">limit: 150 characters</p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input id="nickname" maxlength="50" size="32"/>
    <p class="limit">limit: 50 characters</p>
</div>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/showCharacterCharlimit.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document)
        .ready(function() {
            'use strict';
            $('textarea').characterCounter();
        });

</script>
```

but get me this error :

> TypeError: $(...).characterCounter is not a function

i don't know why, could anybody help me ?

Comment: No clue, I have it working in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsupv7qy/1/)

Comment: @George your fiddle is using jquery 3.2.1, but the OP has the antiquated jquery 1.10.2.  Changing to 1.19 or 2.2 on your fiddle also gives the error - it turns out this is caused by order of load - moving the doc ready to the js and it again works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/jsupv7qy/2/

Comment: It looks like it's because your doc ready is running before the script.  The code in the OP looks like it is in the correct order - can you confirm that your actual code is in this order as well?

Comment: @freedomn-m i change jquery version to 2.2.1 and 3.2.1 even try 'ankit verma' examle but i don't know why dose not work for me

Comment: I'm assuming the 2x fiddles do work for you?  Which confirms there's nothing wrong with your code and it must be how it's implemented (eg order of includes)

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $.fn.characterCounter = function () {
        return this.each(function (index, item) {
            $(item).keyup(function updateCharCounter() {
                var $me = $(this),
                    maxLength = parseInt($me.attr('maxlength'), 10),
                    charCount = $me.val().length,
                    $counter = $me.siblings('.limit');

                $counter.text('limit: ' + maxLength + ' characters. remaining: ' + (maxLength - charCount));
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="short-message" class="wordcount" maxlength="100" cols="8"></textarea>
    <p class="limit">limit: 100 characters</p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="short-shory" class="wordcount" maxlength="150" cols="8"></textarea>
    <p class="limit">limit: 150 characters</p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input id="nickname" class="wordcount" maxlength="50" size="32"/>
    <p class="limit">limit: 50 characters</p>
</div>
<script>
    $(document)
        .ready(function() {
            'use strict';
            $('.wordcount').characterCounter();
        });

</script>
```

Please check , you have a jquery dependency So you need to add jquery for this.
And I used a **Common Class** So that it will work for all type of input fields.

Thanks

Comment: The fact that it's giving *.characterCounter not defined confirms* that the $(document).ready *is* running, so jquery is already available.

Comment: Yes Tan Q this problem from **$(document).ready** when i remve document.ready code work fine